# Please help with my tinkercad code. Debouncing stopwatch with lcd

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, code-review, debounce

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int ssPin = 8;
int resetPin = 9;

bool cntrRunning = false;

int sec = 0;
int min = 0;
double currentMillis;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.print("00:00");
    pinMode(ssPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(resetPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if (digitalRead(ssPin) == HIGH)
    {
        if (cntrRunning)
        {
            stop();
        }
        else
        {
            start();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cntrRunning)
        {
            keepRunning();
        }
        else
        {
            stop();
        }
    }

    if (digitalRead(resetPin) == HIGH)
    {
        if (cntrRunning)
        {
            stop();
            reset();
        }
        else
        {
            reset();
        }
    }
    delay(10);
}

void start()
{
    currentMillis = millis();
    cntrRunning = true;
    Serial.println("started");
}

void keepRunning()
{
    cntrRunning = true;

    if ((millis() - currentMillis) >= 1000)
    {
        sec++;
        currentMillis = millis();
        Serial.println(sec);

        if (sec < 10)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(4,0);
            lcd.print(sec);
        }
        else if (sec == 60)
        {
            min++;
            sec = 0;
            lcd.setCursor(3,0);
            lcd.print("00");
        }
        else
        {
            lcd.setCursor(3,0);
            lcd.print(sec);
        }

        if (min < 10)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(1,0);
            lcd.print(min);
        }
        else if (min == 60)
        {
            min = 0;
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("00");
        }
        else
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print(min);
        }
    }
}

void stop()
{
    cntrRunning = false;
    Serial.println("stopped");
}

void reset()
{
    if (cntrRunning)
    {
        stop();
    }
    reset();
    int sec=0;
    int min=0;
}
```

My professor wants us to add debouncing to the set/stop button but I'm a little confused on how to implement it.

Comment: do you understand the reason why debouncing is required?

Comment: No not entirely.

Comment: ok ... imagine a tennis ball ... hold it high over your head and drop it ... the ball represents the moving contact of a switch ... the floor represents the fixed contact of a switch ... actual switch contacts do something similar to the ball, but in the millisecond realm .... the probem arises in the fact that the microcontroller sees each of the bounces as a keypress

Comment: @Amy, a typical tactile button finishes bouncing and achieves stability after about 50 ms. To test for stability, repeatedly sample the input pin looking for a series of equal values, i.e. 1,1,1,1,1 or 0,0,0,0,0. Your `loop()` runs once every 10 ms, so 5 equal values in a row is 50 ms of stability. Now base your `if` decisions on this stable value.